# How to find source that created byte arrays

Tags: android, ddms

Using DDMS and creating an HPROF I can see a "histogram" view of the data in my app and have noticed an inordinate number of very large "byte[]" objects. I suspect this is the result of a bug or other stupidity in my code. But I don't know how to view either the names of these byte objects or view the location in my source code where they were created. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here: [DDMS Object Allocation Tracking](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#alloc)
it specifies in a step by step how to track down object allocation and find the line of code responsible for it.

> Tracking memory allocation of objects
>
> DDMS provides a feature to track objects that are being allocated to memory and to see  which classes and threads are allocating the objects. This allows you to track, in real time, where objects are being allocated when you perform certain actions in your application. This information is valuable for assessing memory usage that can affect application performance.
>
> To track memory allocation of objects:
>
> - In the Devices tab, select the process that you want to enable allocation tracking for.
> - In the Allocation Tracker tab, click the Start Tracking button to begin allocation tracking. At this point, anything you do in your application will be tracked.
> - Click Get Allocations to see a list of objects that have been allocated since you clicked on the Start Tracking button. You can click on Get Allocations again to append to the list new objects that that have been allocated.
> - To stop tracking or to clear the data and start over, click the Stop Tracking button.
> - Click on a specific row in the list to see more detailed information such as the method and  line number of the code that allocated the object.

Comment: When answering a question by providing an external source, be sure to always include the important parts of that external source in your answer, as links might die over time.